# Make Fn Key 'Sticky'

Tags: windows, fn-key

I would like to make my Fn keys 'sticky' (pressing it once equals to press-and-hold) to make activating some special functions with one hand easier. There's no relevant option in BIOS, and Windows' StickyKeys doesn't stick the Fn keys.

Is there a freebie that affords this?

Answer (score 1):

There are some laptop manufacturers that let you make Fn key sticky. For example, Toshiba provides this utility for some models via [Toshiba Accessibility software](http://toshiba-accessibility.software.informer.com/). The [users manual](http://www.scribd.com/doc/57120362/55/Fn-Sticky-key-Depends-on-the-model-you-purchased) says:

> You can use the TOSHIBA Accessibility Utility to make the Fn key
>   sticky.

Apart from that, some Lenovo models support this function via BIOS settings. I know, for example, T60p has a setting in BIOS:

> Fn Lock: Enabled / Disabled

This lets you make Fn key sticky.

I don't know if there is a global solution for that matter, but you can check your laptop's accessibility settings or BIOS settings to discover if there is one.